# I can't figure out how to change directions while jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to coding, so I'm kind of working blind and deaf here. I have a Unity script for movement and jump controls, but the character can only change direction mid-air if I quickly press a key when I jump, and only once. I'm aware it's intended to be like that, but I would definitely like to learn to change it. I have a feeling it has to do with either the "new" method, but I haven't been able to figure out a different one. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public float maxSpeed = 3.4f;
    public float jumpHeight = 6.5f;
    public float gravityScale = 1.5f;
    public Camera mainCamera;

    bool facingRight = true;
    float moveDirection = 0;
    bool isGrounded = false;
    Vector2 cameraPos;
    Rigidbody2D r2d;
    Collider2D mainCollider;
 
    LayerMask layerMask = ~(1 << 2 | 1 << 8);
    Transform t;

    void Start()
    {
        t = transform;
        r2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        mainCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        r2d.freezeRotation = true;
        r2d.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode2D.Continuous;
        r2d.gravityScale = gravityScale;
        facingRight = t.localScale.x > 0;
        gameObject.layer = 8;

        if (mainCamera)
            cameraPos = mainCamera.transform.position;
    }
     void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) && (isGrounded || r2d.velocity.x > 0.01f))
        {
            moveDirection = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isGrounded || r2d.velocity.magnitude < 0.01f)
            {
                moveDirection = 0;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && isGrounded)
        {
            r2d.velocity = new Vector2(r2d.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
        }
    }

     void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Bounds colliderBounds = mainCollider.bounds;
        Vector2 min = colliderBounds.min;
        Vector2 groundCheckPos = min + new Vector2(colliderBounds.size.x * 0.5f, 0.1f);

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPos, 0.23f, layerMask);

        r2d.velocity = new Vector2 ((moveDirection) * maxSpeed, r2d.velocity.y);

        Debug.DrawLine(groundCheckPos, groundCheckPos - new Vector2(0, 0.23f), isGrounded ? Color.green : Color.red);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `Update()` method.

You should remove  `&& (isGrounded || r2d.velocity.x > 0.01f)` from the first `if` statement if you want the character to be able to change direction all the time. If you don't remove  `&& (isGrounded || r2d.velocity.x > 0.01f)`, you are telling Unity that the character is only allowed to change direction when the it is on the ground or close to the ground (i.e, the `isGrounded` part) or when it is moving (i.e, the `r2d.velocity.x > 0.01f` part).

I think you will be able to change direction whenever you want if you change the `Update()` method to something like:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        moveDirection = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (isGrounded || r2d.velocity.magnitude < 0.01f)
        {
            moveDirection = 0;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && isGrounded)
    {
        r2d.velocity = new Vector2(r2d.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    }
}
```

As for your suspicion about `new`, `new` is a keyword, not a method. It tells the computer to create a new instance of the class/struct written after the `new` keyword. For example, if you write `new Vector2(...)`, you are telling the computer that it should create an instance of a `Vector2`. Check out this page for more info: [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)